# Summation in a loop in fortran

Tags: arrays, sum, fortran

lets say I have the following array: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

I need to define a new array in a way that:

for i=1, the first element of this new array will have the sum of only the first element (so returns the first element of the array)

for i=2, the second element of this array has the sum of the first two elements. etc...

then I need to fill each sum in this array.

Any idea how to do it? I'm new to Fortran and cant figure out how to do it, maybe there is a function to do it.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Be aware that often it is expected to show at least some basic code and to attempt something yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want.  Instead of using implied-do loops, you could use explicit loops.

```
program addup
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: a(:), b(:)
  integer i, n
  n = 10
  a = [(i,i=1,n)]
  b = [(sum(a(1:i)),i=1,n)]
  print '(10(I0,1x))', a
  print '(10(I0,1x))', b
end program addup
```